# How can I put delimiter character which is not confuse with column's content?

Tags: database, csv, delimiter, vertica

I want to export table to `.csv` I use **','** delimiter when exporting. But the weird thing is one of my column of my table has **','** in its content. So When I import **csv** to table it is confused. How can I solve this? How can I show true delimiter.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use  pipe `|`as delimiter, so in most cases there is not conflict with content.

Comment: unfortunately it does conflict with my column :( it has pipe chars

Comment: Surround each field in doublequotes. According to [RFC1480](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) it should work.

Comment: so then How can I understand integer and string ? if every one has doublequotes , there should be some parameter when I want to import from csv to table

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv

Comment: "so then How can I understand integer and string ? if every one has doublequotes"

every value type is represented by a string. Double quote characters are just a way to delimit the contents of a field. It will still be up to Vertica to parse that string value into the appropriate type.