# How to deal with commas and Quotations in data when exporting to a CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, export-to-csv

I have a table that I am exporting via an SQL server table into a CSV file, via the flat file connection manager.

What I have done is in the Flat File Connection Manager I have used " (double-quote) as the Text Qualifier, which keeps the original data in the same column.

However for a couple of cells I run into the problem where the data originally had double-quotation marks and commas within them.

For instance,

> Shaquille "Shaq" O'Neal, LLC

I don't want to change the data within the database. I also don't want to do it the quick and dirty way, ie. "save as xlsx through a query and then save as CSV".

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to do this by escaping the `"`, i.e. `\"`. If there's a comma in the field, the text needs to be in quotes.  Your example would be `"Shaquille \"Shaq\" O'Neal, LLC"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properly escape a double quote in CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)

Comment: Use tabs as your column delimiter and ponder whether you actually need a text delimiter.

Comment: Why do you use double-quote for the text qualifier? Is it important?

Answer (score 0):

Because of your data, you will have to use something else besides "   or    '    as your column delimiters and field separators.   CSV does not mean Comma Delimited Values...it means Character Delimited Values...tho many get it mixed up.   Be creative, use slashes,  # sign, $ sign, ^, &....just be sure the receiving system can match what you are using when you export to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a query in your SSIS package *OLE DB Source or ODBC source* something like this:

```
select 
    id,
    '"' + name + '"',
    '"' + address + '"',
    city,
    zipcode
    FROM yourtable
```

Hope this helps!