# Postgres COPY multibyte delimiter

Tags: postgresql

I have a large body of text and other data that I need to import into Postgres. This text contains all the possible single-byte characters. This means I can't choose ",", ";", "-" or any other single-byte character as a delimiter in my CSV file because it would be confused by the text that contains it.

Is there any way to chose a multibyte character as a delimiter, use multiple characters as a delimiter or use COPY command in some other way to solve this?

Command I'm using:

```
COPY site_articles(id,url,title,content) FROM '/home/sites/site_articles.csv' DELIMITER '^' CSV;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means I can't choose ",", ";", "-" or any other single-byte character as a delimiter in my CSV file because it would be confused by the text that contains it.

[CSV has an escaping mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17808511/398670). Use it. Quote strings that contain the delimiter character `,`, and if the quoted string contains the quote character, double the quote character.

e.g. if you want to represent two values `Fred "wiggle" Smith` and `one, two`, you'd do so as:

```
"Fred ""Wiggle"" Smith","one, two"
```

At time of writing (9.5) `copy` does not support multi-byte characters as delimiters. You can use 3rd party ETL tools like Pentaho Kettle, though.