# How to Deal double quotes and commas within csv string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am dealing with csv file and i am converting it to DataTable.
But it contains strings as follows.

> "Pull PEG Kit, 24" , Ref:P-PEG-24, Exp: 2019/03"

Above phrase is one word. i have used following Regular expression to obtain values within double quotes.

```
"\".*?\""
```

But in this scenario it break the word as

> "Pull PEG Kit, 24"
>
> Ref:P-PEG-24
>
> Exp: 2019/03"

but i need the word

> Pull PEG Kit, 24" , Ref:P-PEG-24, Exp: 2019/03

how can i solve this using c#?
please help me to solve this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you define the context where `"` should be considered part of the single field? If you cannot, regex won't help.

Comment: why don't you just use string's `Trim('"')` method?

Comment: Note that the csv is invalid at the moment, a double-quote in the value `"` should be escaped like that: `""`. Also why using regex if there are csv parser available?

Comment: double quotes in the value means 24 inches.. What is csv parser? can you  provide me a reference?

Comment: @BonieZat Yeah, but what I meant is a text like `te" xt` saved as csv should result in `"te"" xt"` in order to [escape the double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17808731/4465512). One way to read csv files is shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3508572/4465512)

Comment: The CSV string is invalid. How can a *CSV* pattern know to *not stop* at an internal quote and comma? It appears that you have a CSV with internal CSVs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something out here, but the most basic solution yields the reuslt you need:

```
var regex = new Regex("(.*)");
var str = "Pull PEG Kit, 24\", Ref:P - PEG - 24, Exp: 2019 / 03";
var result = regex.Match(str);

Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

Output:

```
Pull PEG Kit, 24", Ref:P - PEG - 24, Exp: 2019 / 03
```

If the surrounding double quotes are part of the source string:

```
var regex = new Regex("(.*)");
var str = "\"Pull PEG Kit, 24\", Ref:P - PEG - 24, Exp: 2019 / 03\"";
var result = regex.Match(str);

Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
Console.WriteLine(result.Value.Trim('\"'));
```

Just trim them out.