# How i can convert my .xlsx excel sheet file to a valid .csv file. when some excel cells contains ","

Tags: excel, csv, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I want to convert my `.xlsx` excel sheet file to a `.csv` file, to export it inside my SQL server 2008 using Import Data wizard. So i follow these steps:-

1. I open my `.xlsx` excel sheet inside Microsoft Excel 2010 application.
2. I click Save As.
3. I chose CSV file type as follow:-
   [image]
4. i went to SQL Server >> Import Export Data (64X), as follow:-
   [image]
5. i browse for the .csv and do the mapping, as follow:-
   [image]

then i continue with the wizard, which created a new Database table for me , but the problem is that inside my original .xlsx file i already have some cell which contain `,` character, so inside the .csv file it will map the data wrongly , since the `,` is used to define data separators inside the .csv. so can anyone adivce how i can overcome this problem ?? can i convert my .xlsx file into a valid .csv file, where it will add any `,` found insde the .xlsx cells as part of the data itself and not as a seperator inside the .csv file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with commas in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769621/dealing-with-commas-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: This is why CSV wraps each value in double quotes so that when the CSV is imported the "'s denote values even if a comma exists. and why " must be escaped and no need to worry about the comma.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv  look at the CSV on export in notepad or notepad++ each value is enclosed in double quotes and separated by a `,` right? so comma's don't cause your problem.  Double quotes could though.

Comment: Just import Excel file directly. Why do you bother converting it to CSV? See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-data-from-excel-to-sql

Comment: @xQbert now if i save as my .xlsx file using the MS Excel program and i chose "CSV (Comma delimited)" from the Save as type, then the generated .csv will not contain any double quotes (unless the excel sheet contain " inside its cells).. the generated .csv file it will only add `,` after each excel sheet cell. and if the cell itself contain `,` then nothing will indicate this.on the other hand if i chose "CSV (MS-DOS)" when i save as my .xlsx file, then as you mentioned the .csv file will wrap any cell which have `,`

Comment: @xQbert  with double quotes, but saving my .xlsx file as "CSV (MS-DOS)" will do wrong characters encoding , for example `å` will be saved as `†`,, while saving the .xlsx file as "CSV (comma delimted)" will not have any character encoding problems

Comment: @Alex i tried to directly import the .xlsx file using the import export data wizard but i got this error `The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. (System.Data)`..

Comment: @johnG, you can download it from MS (https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: @johnG - one more thing, I assume you are running SSMS on a different machine to SQL Server, as installing this provider on the machine with SQL Server may require a reboot.