# How to correctly escape quotes in a csv?

Tags: csv, quotes

I have a recordset of a database and should write
it row by row into a csv file.

Now it is possible, that there are quotes in a field which leads to 
an invalid formed csv.

field = This leads"; to problems

In the csv file [ ; ] is the delimeter and ["..."] the field capture.

How to correctly escape the quotes ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly escape a double quote in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)

Comment: Possible duplicate of Properly escape a double quote in CSV. Correct solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17808731/4954434

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to replace all <"> in the string with <"">

```
vba:
Replace(field,Chr(34),Chr(34) & Chr(34))
```

ore more generic

```
pseudo
quote = "\""
replace(field,quote,quote + quote)
```

reference was
[@tommed to the answer of user4035](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)