# How can I use SED to replace a specific character in a substring

Tags: regex, csv, sed

So, i have a csv file with multiple lines like

```
"ABC-DEF-d98263","12345678","176568981","","588","ABC-DEF-11947","","GAUZE PACKING STRIPS 1/4"","","","2019-02-04T19:09:00-05:00","","XXX","XXX","2019-02-12T23:57:48-06:00","XXX-XXX-176568981"
"ABC-DEF-d1494751","98765432","98765432","1073552394","284","ABC-DEF-77997","","ACE WRAP 3"","","","2015-10-29T18:45:00-07:00","Sent","XXX","XXX","2018-04-05T19:38:41-05:00","XXX-XXX-76954940"
```

I would like to replace the  `"",` with `",` only for the column 8 or where its after GAUZE PACKING STRIPS 1/4, or ACE WRAP 3 without touching other `"",` in the line.

Have tried `sed 's/[[:alnum:]]""//g' file.csv` but it removes `<num>""` as well.

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the quotes you have issues with actually denote inches (`3/4"` and `3"`).  You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/ before you go down the route as suggested by your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use capture groups to match and replace anything that is between double quotes and followed immediately by double quotes.

The regex to match would look something like this: `("[^",]*")"`. Note two things: the first one is that `"` are matched literally and the expression in the middle `[^",]*` just means that the regex will match anything except a `"` or a `,`. This means it will prevent the matched string from having a quote inside.

Lastly, the parenthesis are a *capture group* and we can reference anything that matched the sub-regex between the `()` with a backslash and a number. For example, `\1` will be replaced by the match of the first capture group, `\3` with the third and so on.

The sed script for what you need may look something like this:

```
sed -re 's/("[^",]*")"/\1/g'
```

See how the last double quote is outside the capture group, and it will not be replaced with the `\1`.

Capture groups are a feature of Extended Regular Expressions (ERE), so the flag `-r` is needed to enable them in sed, otherwise it will use Basic Regular Expressions (BRE).

Notice also the `/g` at the end. This is needed for sed to be able to match and replace more than one occurrence in the same line.

Example:

```
$ cat test
"ABC-DEF-d98263","12345678","176568981","","588","ABC-DEF-11947","","GAUZE PACKING STRIPS 1/4"","","","2019-02-04T19:09:00-05:00",""","XXX","XXX","2019-02-12T23:57:48-06:00"","XXX-XXX-176568981"
$ cat test | sed -re 's/("[^",]*")"/\1/g'
"ABC-DEF-d98263","12345678","176568981","","588","ABC-DEF-11947","","GAUZE PACKING STRIPS 1/4","","","2019-02-04T19:09:00-05:00","","XXX","XXX","2019-02-12T23:57:48-06:00","XXX-XXX-176568981"
```

Comment: This one worked really well! Thank you :) Since I was working with a lot of files, I added an extra parameter to keep it silent and make the changes infile. `sed -i -re 's/("[^",]*")"/\1/g' file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }           # set delimiters
{
    if($8!="\"\"")             # if $8 is not empty ie. ""
        sub(/\"\"$/,"\"",$8)   # replace trailing double quotes with a single double quote
}1' file                       # output
```

Output:

```
"ABC-DEF-d98263","12345678","176568981","","588","ABC-DEF-11947","","GAUZE PACKING STRIPS 1/4","","","2019-02-04T19:09:00-05:00","","XXX","XXX","2019-02-12T23:57:48-06:00","XXX-XXX-176568981"
"ABC-DEF-d1494751","98765432","98765432","1073552394","284","ABC-DEF-77997","","ACE WRAP 3","","","2015-10-29T18:45:00-07:00","Sent","XXX","XXX","2018-04-05T19:38:41-05:00","XXX-XXX-76954940"
```