# Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 1830577. Error: Data between close double quote (") and field separator

Tags: bq-load

Im trying to load a table from Teradata to BQ. My pipeline is first export the table data to a gcs location and then using bqload, loading the data from gs:// to the bq table.

My bqload looks like this

```
bq load --autodetect --source_format=CSV --project_id=xx-xx-xx --field_delimiter='^' \
BQTable \
gs:// \
Name:string,Age:INT64,Place:NUMERIC ...
```

But i get the below error, when im trying to load the data into the bq table using bq load

```
Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 1830577. Error: Data between
close double quote (") and field separator.
```

I tried using couple of options in the bqload command, like --quote ="" , when i used this, it gave me a different error like below

```
Could not parse 'MP' as NUMERIC for field XXXXXX (position 18) starting at
location 1030399 with message 'Invalid NUMERIC value: MP'
```

Played around with other options as well for long time, but nothing gave me the result. Can someone throw some light?

Answer (score 4):

I have run into this issue a number of times and found it hard to figure out until I Googled around for some bash help.

So my message, like yours is:

```
Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 493727436.
Error: Data between close double quote (") and field separator.
```

I found that I can isolate that exact byte by calling `tail -c` with `+`;

```
tail -c +493727436 myfile.csv
```

However my file is really long so I tailed a few bytes before and piped to `head` to get first 100 bytes

```
tail -c +493727386 myfile.csv | head -c 100
```

Comment: Thank you John Smith for the edit, it adds clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still active question but maybe it will help someone in the future.

Looks like have some data incorrectly closed in double quotes (e.g. `123,"some" data,456`).
It may be caused by escaping special characters - see more about data with double quotes here: [Properly escape a double quote in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)
and here:
https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43250/admin_guide/load/topics/g-escaping-in-csv-formatted-files.html

Note that NULL value is also escaped by default with "
this may cause some extra trouble, like:
e.g. `123,"NULL,"some text value in quotes",456`
then "NULL," would be interpreted as string value and 'some text...' would throw

```
Error: Data between close double quote (") and field separator.
```

You should get rid off any `"NULL` from your .csv file so it would look like this:
`123,,"some text value in quotes",456`