# When I view the csv files in Excel they looks OK. In notepad++ a few lines are split, causing the SSIS import to fail

Tags: c#, csv, ssis

Example output viewing the CSV in Notepad and Excel

Notepad++

```
1234,"50 the Street",45,60.88,87
5678,"50 the Road
50 the Road",65,70.99,98
9101,"50 the Avenue",12,09.00,43
```

Excel

[image]

In Notepad++, the second line is split into two rows, with the text field repeated on both. The text delimiter (") shows at the beginning on the first row and the end on the second.  Opening the CSV in Excel the line is not split and the text isn't duplicated.

I have multiple files to import, each about 300k rows and 45 columns.  These files are generated on a regular basis for import (I have no control over generating the CSV files).  Can anyone explain why this difference exists and if there is a work around? I don't want to have to manually edit every CSV after its been generated.
Thank you.

Comment: There is a CrLF at the end of the text field when I look in Notepadd++.  Why would this duplicate the text and not cause a new line in Excel?

Comment: A valid CSV may contain fields with line breaks if they are wrapped in quotes. This CSV looks valid. Excel most likely imports the text fully which you can see by widening the second row. In SSIS you probably haven't set up the text delimiters for your fields to be `"`.

Comment: _"Why would this duplicate the text and not cause a new line in Excel"_ does it, though? If there is a CRLF and duplicated text in Notepad++, then it is there in the CSV content. What Excel does during import is another story.

Comment: The second line has only one double quote.

Comment: @jdweng Because the other double quote is [on the third line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules).

Comment: Is there any way to fix this via SSIS (C# in script component if needed)? I cant think of a way to find these issues?  There are around 10 in each file of 300k rows.  Or am I better of saving each as an Excel and importing it as an Excel source?

Comment: You have a Flat File component in SSIS. You set it up there.

Comment: @Gserg the Flat File component cant read the file in the same way Excel does.  I need the file to look like it does in Excel.  With the flat file component it tries to import the data as it is split like in notepadd++.  There is a CRLF at the end of the text field and no closing text delimeter.

Comment: @CMR https://i.stack.imgur.com/vro9f.png

Comment: Thanks @GSerg.  The raw file has multiple instances of Quotes within the text delimeters which means I cant just specify it in the import. The only way Ive got it imported so far is by converting it to Excel first

Comment: I lost track of the issue.  Your test data, if you open that in excel you get the multiple lines as shown in the text.  Click on that cell and you will see:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUGun.png.   Flat file connector can handle that as @GSerg is pointing out.  Is there other data situations not shared here? Can you share a sample of what you mean by "multiple instances of quotes with the text delimiters"?

Comment: The text field is not duplicated in Excel (agree it is in the example I posted but not when I use the full csv), I dont understand why.  I have sites like "Company Name "Main Plant" Area 2" - there are a few text fields for company name, address etc.

Comment: Ive opened all csv files in Excel and saved them as xlsx files.  These have now all imported without issue.  Its not a process I want to keep but it'll have to do for this year!

Comment: So what you are saying is that you have invalid CSV files where the quoted multiline fields have quotes in them. If the files are indeed invalid, fix the generation process to [escape the quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17808511/11683) in the quoted fields.