# Csv not getting loaded int BIgquery issue with "\ double quotes and delimeter repeated twice

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Faing issue loading below row into BQ. I have already tried suggestion given on stackoverflow but no luck. Below is my data:

Id;description;curator_id;Q_code;ITG_NUM
ABC;”weather is good for skiing \”B\””;ROLLON;HFCKQ:5051
CDE;"NO wonder it is good"B"";;MOVEON;CKHLP;5058

I have added below parameters as suggested:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        autodetect=True,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
        quote_character = '"',
        encoding='UTF-8',
        field_delimiter=';',
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        skip_leading_rows=1,
    )
```

But still getting error:
Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 155482.
Error: Data between close double quote (") and field separator.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Both the quoted B look dodgy. The double quote should be doubled not backslash-scaped. I.e. “blah-di-blah “”B””” - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv#17808731

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Properly escape a double quote in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808511/properly-escape-a-double-quote-in-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the data file in Notepad++ with Word Wrap turned off, press Ctrl G, then select "Offset" radio button and then you can put your position # 155482 to search.  This will take you to the position where the error resides/is detected.  Most likely, it's an embedded double-quote in the data field (between your comma delimiters).

Comment: so i am trying to replace using below command but it is not .Any suggestion:for line in reading_file:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  new_line = stripped_line.replace('\"', '"')
reading_file.close()
new_file_content += new_line+"\n"

writing_file = open("file", "w")
writing_file.write(new_file_content)
writing_file.close()

Comment: answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826512/replace-with-in-python-files