# replace '\"' with " in python files

Tags: python-3.x, csv, replace

I am trying to read line and then replacing '"' this with '"' .Is there any issue my code .It is getting executed but not replacing those two characters:

```
# Read in the file
with open('filename', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
  filedata = filedata.replace('\"', ' "')

with open('filename', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're asking. What I understood is you want to replace `\"` with `"`.

In which case, you would be missing another backlash as backslash itself is a special character which you need to escape using `\`

```
with open('filename', 'r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace('\\"', '"')
```