# Why a comma can be missed in a printf() call?

Tags: c

I am used to C# or Java.

How could the following statement be correct in C?

`printf("aaa" "bbb");`

On my Xubuntu 15.04 with GCC 4.9. It outputs:

`aaabbb`

And as I tried, below works too!

```
CHAR *p = "aaa""bbb""ccc";
printf(p);
```

It outputs:

```
aaabbbccc
```

I think there should be a comma but in that way, the first string will be treated as a format string. So, is this syntax legal?

Comment: This is the syntax for concatening two strings. Putting a comma will not work since it will be interpreted as two different function's arguments

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/254984/on-concatenating-adjacent-string-literals

Comment: `"aaa" "bbb"` in C is 100% equivalent to Java `"aaa" + "bbb"`. Only difference is that C doesn't force you to write `+`all over the place.

Comment: Also see [Why allow concatenation of string literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2504536/1708801)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is legal syntax because of **translation phase 6** in ISO C99, #5.1.1.2 Translation phases:

> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Comment: This is most authoritative.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned adjacent strings are concatenated by the compiler. But if you want to see some difference you may add a `\0` null terminator in your strings.

On adding the `aaa\0` your o/p will be just `aaa` as printf will print till it finds the 1st `\0` null terminator.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

printf("aaa\0" "bbb");

}
```

Output

`aaa`

Comment: I know that '\0' is treated as the ending sign of a string in C. But do I need to explicitly add it to the end of a string? Like this `"aaa\0"`?

Comment: hmm...very explicit! The `"aaa""bbb\0""ccc"` outputs `aaabbb`. But I think the compiler still makes a `aaabbb\0ccc\0`. But the `printf()` stops at the first `\0'.

Comment: You do not need to add it yourself, the compiler will do so for you, but only when it realizes the string has ended, so char* s = "as" will be null terminated by compiler, but char* q = "as" "ca" will be null terminated only after "ca"

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies I agree the compiler adds it by default for you but printf executes till firs `\0`

Comment: @smwikipedia agree with you

Comment: @VinayShukla indeed, the printf will print the string, and the first time it sees "\0" it will stop

Answer (score 5):

The two strings are just concatenated by the *compiler*.

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler see two consecutive string *literals*, it concatenate them (at parsing time in the compiler), like you observe. This won't work (compiler syntax error) for non literals.

The [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is unrelated to concatenation. It evaluates first the left operand, then the right one, and discards the result of the left, giving the right result. It is useful for side effects (like `progn` in Lisp, `;` in Ocaml, `begin` in Scheme). Of course, the comma is also used to separate arguments in calls.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jens said, adjacent string literals are concatenated by the compiler.

One reason for this is so that you can do preprocessor things like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(__linux__)
#define MY_OS "linux"
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#define MY_OS "windows"
#else
#define MY_OS "probably something BSD-derived"
#endif

int main(void){
    printf("my os is " MY_OS "\n");
}
```

Which saves everybody a lot of time.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the main reason. Probably, the main reason is to be able to enter a very long multiline string literal constants without using backslashes at end of line.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch true, I didn't mean to imply it was the only reason :L