# Python operator precedence when concatenating adjacent string literals

Tags: python

The docs say that two string literals that are next to each other are concatenated. For example:

```
>>>print("py" "thon")
python
```

However, this feature is implemented at compile time instead of runtime like the + and * operators, so this interesting effect occurs:

```
>>>print(2 * "py" + "thon")
pypython
>>>print(2 * "py" "thon")
pythonpython
```

I understand why this happens in the language, but I can't think of a reason for it to be that way. Is there a reason, or was it just easier to leave it alone?

Comment: It is yet another loophole around pythons requirement to put things on a single line.

Comment: I guess this is happening because python does not treat the literal concatenation as an operation in the first case. 
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite frankly, If I were to design `python` today, I would make

```
print ("py" "thon")
```

A syntax error

Same as

```
print (5 3)
```

I would guess that the reason for concatenating adjacent strings, is for consistency with bash / perl

```
echo "py""thon"
```

Comment: That's a good point. Now that I think of it, I know of no scenario where you won't be able to use a + operator.

Comment: There are good reasons to allow string literal concatenation for visualization purposes (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504536/why-allow-concatenation-of-string-literals). However, the question is about why this is implemented at compile time rather than run time